# NLTK lemmatizer received error BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I am trying to use the lemmatizer from NLTK package but I had this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Documents/NLP course/exercise.py:21
    print(wn.lemmatize('meanness'))

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/stem/wordnet.py:45 in lemmatize
    lemmas = wn._morphy(word, pos)

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py:121 in __getattr__
    self.__load()

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py:81 in __load
    root = nltk.data.find(f"{self.subdir}/{self.__name}")

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py:555 in find
    return find(modified_name, paths)

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py:542 in find
    return ZipFilePathPointer(p, zipentry)

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/compat.py:41 in _decorator
    return init_func(*args, **kwargs)

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py:394 in __init__
    zipfile = OpenOnDemandZipFile(os.path.abspath(zipfile))

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/compat.py:41 in _decorator
    return init_func(*args, **kwargs)

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py:935 in __init__
    zipfile.ZipFile.__init__(self, filename)

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py:1269 in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py:1336 in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

my code is as below:

```
import string
import re
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
wn = WordNetLemmatizer()

print(wn.lemmatize('meanness'))
print(wn.lemmatize('meaning'))
```

Action taken so far but still couldn't solve it:

1. I have tried uninstalled the nltk package using conda uninstall nltk and re downloaded it
2. I have also tried deleting the nltk_data file and download the file again using nltk.download(). I noticed that then the window popped up to download the file, the status of the files are 'out of date' and I also received an error 'Error with downloaded zip file'

How to resolve this?

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post to include the full error trace (and remove any code that may come *after* the error) - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: You may need to download additional packages, such as `import nltk; nltk.download('wordnet')`.

Comment: Downloaded 'wordnet' and I still have the same error

Comment: I can run your code without errors. It seems that [issues with nltk](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) data files are quite common. People blame internet connections/ISPs/network, they can't unzip downloaded files, etc. Check if the file is corrupted. `import zipfile; wzip = '/<paht to your nltk_data dir>/corpora/wordnet.zip'; print([zifo for zifo in zipfile.ZipFile(wzip).infolist()])`. Should return a list containing a ZipInfo object for each archive member.

Comment: This error message (BadZipFile: File is not a zip file) means that Python's zipfile module cannot process your zip file. The 'Error with downloaded zip file' is raised in [nltk downloader (def _unzip_iter)](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/downloader.html). This is actually the same BadZipFile error, only with the custom message text.